# Create column for continuation of text in the same window?

Tags: laravel, fpdf

I have a return that comes from the database, where it is a text, where the content of a course is listed, display the data in two columns so that another page is not generated, so all content is more organized.

This is my code where I'm adapting all your routine, I've looked for several ways to solve it, including on the fpdf documentation site itself, but nothing solved according to my need.

```
class PdfController extends Controller
```

{
protected $fpdf;

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->fpdf = new Fpdf;
    
}

public $angle = 0;


public function index() 
{

    $user = Auth::user()->name;
    

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////// TRÁS AS INFORMAÇÕES DO CERTIFICADO, CURSO E PROFESSOR ///////
    $certificate = DB::table('certificates')
                        ->join('courses', 'courses.id', '=', 'certificates.coursecert_id')
                        ->join('teachers', 'teachers.id', '=', 'courses.teacher_id')
                        ->select('courses.*', 'teachers.*', 'certificates.*')
                        ->where('courses.status', '=', 2)
                        ->get();
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    
    $certfront = "storage/cert/cert-front.jpg";
    $certback = "storage/cert/cert-back.jpg";
    $signature = "storage/cert/signature.jpg";
    
    setlocale( LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.iso-8859-1', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese' );
    date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Sao_Paulo' );


    foreach ($certificate as $cert) {

        
        ////////////// PRIMEIRA PAGINA ////////////////////
        $this->fpdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);
        
        $this->fpdf->AddPage("L");
        $this->fpdf->SetLineWidth(1.5);
        
        // desenha a imagem do certificado
        $this->fpdf->Image($certfront,0,0,300);

        // Mostrar texto no topo
        $this->fpdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 18); // Tipo de fonte e tamanho
        $this->fpdf->SetXY(32,46); //Parte chata onde tem que ficar ajustando a posição X e Y
        $this->fpdf->MultiCell(235, 10, $cert->name, '', 'C', 0); // Tamanho width e height e posição

        // Mostrar o nome
        $this->fpdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 30); // Tipo de fonte e tamanho
        $this->fpdf->SetXY(18,72); //Parte chata onde tem que ficar ajustando a posição X e Y
        $this->fpdf->MultiCell(265, 10, $user, '', 'C', 0); // Tamanho width e height e posição

        // Mostrar o conteúdo
        $this->fpdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 15); // Tipo de fonte e tamanho
        $this->fpdf->SetTextColor(52, 50, 50);
        $this->fpdf->SetXY(28,92); //Parte chata onde tem que ficar ajustando a posição X e Y
        $this->fpdf->MultiCell(245, 10, iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', html_entity_decode($cert->contentcert)), '', 'C', 0); // Tamanho width e height e posição
        
        // Mostrar a data no final
        $this->fpdf->SetXY(32,172); //Parte chata onde tem que ficar ajustando a posição X e Y
        $this->fpdf->Image($signature,38,130,100);

        //////////////////// SEGUNDA PAGINA //////////////////////
        $this->fpdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);
        
        $this->fpdf->AddPage("L");
        $this->fpdf->SetLineWidth(1.5);
        
        // desenha a imagem do certificado
        $this->fpdf->Image($certback,0,0,300);

        // Mostrar o conteúdo
        $this->fpdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 8); // Tipo de fonte e tamanho
        $this->fpdf->SetTextColor(52, 50, 50);
        $this->fpdf->SetXY(32,35); //Parte chata onde tem que ficar ajustando a posição X e Y
        
        $this->fpdf->MultiCell(530, 2,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $cert->contentcourse), '', 'L', 0); // Tamanho width e height e posição
        


        $this->fpdf->Output();

        exit;

    }

    
}
```

}

Resultado:
[image]

Can anyone give me some help?

Comment: Did you saw [this](http://fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto4.htm) tutorial on fpdf.org?

Comment: it didn't print the value on the screen, I've tried to change this code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: MDN is an excellent reference.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns for "multi-column output".

Comment: This css column-count attribute doesn't work in fpdf :/